# How do I animate an element when it's removed?

Tags: css, css-animations

The animation below makes my element slide up when it's displayed (an error message).

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
            transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
@keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40%);
            transform: translateY(40%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

-webkit-animation: slide-top 3s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
          animation: slide-top 3s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
```

But I would like to apply the same animation also when the element is removed, then it should slide back down.

Comment: Define: "removed", Also you don't need `@-webkit-keyframes` anymore - it's been unnecessary since 2015.

Comment: Could you provide us with the HTML and the JS used for the error message?

Comment: I don't know how to extract it from the Dev Tools... this is a Stripe payment on Woocommerce.

Comment: Do you want the error-message to slide-up (remove) after a givent time?

Comment: Hi @SirPilan, i want slide-down (remove). The element is displayed with a slide up. So the removal needs slide-down.

Comment: @AdamAlleman Sadly that doesnt answer my question.

Comment: Sorry. No. I just want it to slide down when the error message is removed.